# Creating an Instance WPF InlineCollection

Tags: .net, wpf, collections, html

I'm populating a  class programtically at runtime, and started by building a collection of InlineCollection classes.  However, InlineCollection class cannot be instantiated.

My question is, how do I add a collection of inlines to Span.Inlines whose type is InlineCollection, if I can't create an Instance of it?

Basically I need a collection of a collection of Inline classes, so I can randomally set Span.Inlines to a new collection of Inline classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163371.aspx

It looks like what you want to do is:

```
span.Inlines.Add(new Run("Some normal text"));
var b = new Bold();
b.Inlines.Add(new Run(" Some bold text"));
span.Inlines.Add(b);
```

Comment: Thanks, but what I need is to be able to do something like Collection<InlineCollection>, but I can't add an instance of InlineCollection.  I want to setup a collection of InlineCollection classes so I can set span.Inlines at runtime to one of the objects in the collection.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I guess I could just create a collection of Run objects, then add the inlines I need to each Run object in the collection?!

Comment: @Carl: I think your second suggestion is the right way to go about it.

Answer (score 4):

yes, as you cannot instantiate `InlineCollection` class, but what you can do is to use for example `List<Inline>` and populate this.

later it is easy to apply them to, for example, a `TextBlock`:

```
// create some inlines
List<Inline> inlines = new List<Inline>();
inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = "text" });
Span span = new Span();
span.Inlines.AddSafe(new Run() { Text = "text inside span" });
inlines.Add(span);

// now apply to a TextBlock
TextBlock tb = new TextBlock() { TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap };
tb.Inlines.Clear();
foreach (Inline i in inlines)
    tb.Inlines.Add(i);
```